# Sending Stripe.com funds to a PayPal account

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments

So, i'm making a donation platform, kinda like gofund.me, where you can create a page and people can send you donations! Upon creating a page, it will ask you for your PayPal username/email. This is asked because every donation will be sent to the PayPal username/email provided.
Now, I want to enable Stripe payments for the donation page, so users can donate via using their Credit/Debit card... but I came across an issue.
Once they complete the transaction, how can I send the money that they donated via Stripe to the PayPal username/email that the donation page set up?
Is there an API for that? Thanks :)

BTW... I am using HTML, CSS, and JS for this project

Comment: http://www.kylembrown.com/stripe/does-stripe-integrate-with-paypal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to send money from Stripe to PayPal. To send money to a PayPal email, you are better off simply [accepting the payment via PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/), and either:

- Sending it from your PayPal account (where you received it) via Payouts (if [approved for the Payouts feature](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-access-to-paypal-payouts))
- More simply, having the payer send it directly to [the target PayPal account (payee) at checkout time](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/pay-another-account/)